# Gmail meter (Google apps script) sends error notifications even after deleting the file with script

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've installed Gmail Meter script in Google Documents and launched it. It demanded many permissions and access to many google account elements. Script works quite slowly and meanwhile I decided to take back those permissions because they were too wide. An hour later I got mail notification about error, script cannot work without permissions.
I tried to turn off this working script but didn't find the way so I deleted (permanently) the file in which I installed the script. Since then I get every day 3 error notifications. I can turn off them (there is a link in a mail) but I'm more interested in terminating the script? What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Indeed the triggers should be terminated once the spreadsheet has been moved to trash. This is a known issue:
[Issue 143: Spreadsheets with time triggered scripts should no longer trigger when spreadsheet is deleted](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=143)

You can star this issue and turn the triggers off via the link in the email.

Answer (score 2):

You can access all your script projects by opening [the script editor](https://docs.google.com/macros/) and selecting **Resources > All your triggers**. Find the triggers you want to delete and click the 'x' icon next to them.

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the triggers ...